# Adding UISplitViewController as a subview to UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I am stuck on something in my ipad project. Now I have a UIViewController and I want to add UISplitViewController as a subview. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[myViewController.view addSubview:mySplitviewController.view];
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: ok but when i want to create mySplitViewController class what should be the subview of it

Comment: the splitviewcontroller should contain 2 viewcontrollers inside it in its viewControllers property. Read the [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) for split view controllers for details.

Comment: For same functionality i have followed this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906738/display-a-splitviewcontroller-from-uiviewcontroller-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, click on the Storyboard that contains your UIViewController, drag a UISplitViewController onto the storyboard, then control-drag a segue between your UIViewController and the UISplitViewController.

Comment: The problem is i do not use storyboard. I have one viewController and have contentview inside. I want to put my SplitViewController as a subview there.

Comment: You might consider creating a test project using a storyboard.  Start with a single UIViewController and then add in the UISplitViewController.  Once you get that working, you'll be better able to do it programmatically.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
[myViewController.view addSubview: mySplitviewController.view];
[myViewController addChildViewController: mySplitviewController];
```

Comment: Your code should contain a description for both the OP and the future readers. Code only as answer is not promoted on SO.